# $m$-Trees are Infinite.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Let $\Gamma$ be a tree, and $m \ge 2$. If $\Gamma$ is an $m$-tree (all vertices have valence of $m$), then $\Gamma$ is infinite.

My idea is to prove it by contradiction. Suppose that $\Gamma$ is finite yet every vertex has a valence of $m$. I suspect that I should be able to contradict the formula $|V(\Gamma)| = |E(\Gamma)| + 1$, but I don't know how to count $|E(\Gamma)|$. Given $n := |V(\Gamma)|$, what is $|E(\Gamma)|$? I'm having hard time determining this. I tried several examples, but I couldn't discern a pattern/formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be that complicated. You can directly construct an infinite path in $\Gamma$. Start at some vertex $v_0$. Since $v_0$ has valence $m \geq 2$, we can choose a neighbor $v_1$ of $v_0$. Now $v_1$ has valence $m \geq 2$, so we can choose a neighbor $v_2 \neq v_0$ of $v_1$. Now $v_2$ has valence $m \geq 2$, so we can choose a neighbor $v_3 \neq v_1$ of $v_2$. We have to check that $v_2 \neq v_0$ though... why can't this happen? Continue in this fashion.

Comment: So, in other words, prove the following claim by induction: for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there are $n$ distinct vertices in $\Gamma$?

Comment: Or even stronger, for every $n$ there is a path of length $n$ (a path by definition consists of distinct vertices). This phrasing makes the inductive step easier.

Comment: Why does path have to consist of distinct vertices? Aren't loops/circuits considered paths? Here's the definition of (edge) path in my book: "An edge path, or more simply a path, in a graph consists of an alternating sequence of vertices and edges, $\{v_0,e_1,v_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,v_n\}$ where $ENDS(e_i) = \{v_{i-1},v_i\}$ (for each $i$)."

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)): "In graph theory, a path in a graph is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which join a sequence of vertices **which, by most definitions, are all distinct from one another.**" It sounds like your book is an exception to this, in which case you should say "a path of distinct vertices." Your book may use the terminology "simple path" to mean a path of distinct vertices.

Comment: Okay. Here's an attempt. Given $v_0 \in V(\Gamma)$, because $v_0$ has valence $m \ge 2$, there is must at least one other vertex $v_1$ connected to $v_0$ by some edge $e_1$. Hence, $\{v_0,e_1,v_1\}$ is a edge path of length $2$ (this the base case). Now suppose that we have an edge path $\{v_0,e_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,v_n\}$ of length $n$. The vertex $v_n$ is already connected to $v_{n-1}$, so the number of other vertices it can be connected to is $m-1 \ge 1$...

Comment: Hence, there is at least one other vertex $v$ to which it connects by edge $e$. If $v = v_i$ for some $i = 0,...,n-1$, then $\{v_{i},e_{i+1},...,v_{n-1},e_n,v_n,e,v_i\}$, which is a cycle. But this cannot be, for $\Gamma$ is a tree. Hence, $\{v_0,e_1,...,v_{n-1},e_n,v_n, e, v \}$ is a path of length $n+1$ (i.e., has $n+1$ distinct vertices).

Comment: That looks good, but you should specify in your inductive hypothesis that the edge path consists of all distinct vertices (since this is the statement you are trying to prove).